# How to add integer constructors and public signatures java

Tags: java, class, constructor, integer, arguments

Hi i had this question on my mock exam

In Java code, write class called Student with the following features:
• a private instance variable int studentNumber that is initialised to zero.
• a private instance variable String firstName;
• a private instance variable String lastName;
• a constructor which takes an integer argument and two String arguments to
initialises the three respective data items.
• a public method with signature equals(Student s) . . .

so far this is my code

```
public class student {
private int studentnumber = 0;

public student () {
firstname= "forename":
lastname="surname":

public student (integer studentnumber, string firstname, string lastname) {

this.firstname= firstname
this.lastname= lastname:
```

My question is how do i add the integer in the argument do i have to use int =? and how would i go about doing the public signature equals any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2):

Correction in your current code:

You spelled it Wrong. You are almost done and there is no `integer` in java. There is `Integer`

Answer for your second question :

You can even use `int`, since autoboxing unboxing avaialble since jdk 1.5.

As you are new , you must follow [java naming conventions.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58)

```
field: fBlahBlah
argument: aBlahBlah
local variable: blahBlah
constant: BLAH_BLAH
class: BlahBlah
interface: BlahBlah (same as class)
```

Comment: also `string`, then `:` instead of `;` and no naming convention, and no closing bracket for default constructor

Comment: Or maybe he just needs an `int`.

Comment: ah sorry for the error, yh its just the last bit im having trouble with kinda at a standstill

Comment: Also, the class name and constuctors should begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: yh sorry for the common mistakes kinda new to this, so in the argument would it just be int = studentnumber ?

Comment: sorry im a bit confused at the moment in terms of the int would it just be a simple case of int = studentnumber?

Comment: @jag - Yes, a simple `this.studentNumber=studentNumber` in your constructor would work.

Comment: thank you lost mind appreciate that gonna have a read into the public signature equals now

Answer (score 0):

A Hint: You need to look at any implementation of `equals` to get a fair idea.

```
equals(Object obj2){
// if this.field1 ==obj2.field1 && .. check for all fields (use .equals() for String)
}
```

Note :

If you override `equals()`, you must also override `hashCode()`